# Issues performing math on nested Sass loop indexes

Tags: sass

For some reason when I am trying to do calculations on nest loop indexes I am getting a type error that says percentage() is not being passed a number.

```
@for $step from 0 through 20 {
  @for $total from 0 through 20 {
    $percentage: percentage($step/$total);

    .progress-#{$step}-#{$total} {
      background: linear-gradient(to right,  #0c91f0 $percentage,#dedfe3 $percentage);
    }
  }
}
```

Both $step and $total are numbers and performing a division should certainly return a number, I am at a loss as to why this doesn't calculate.

Comment: Cannot reproduce a type error at all: http://sassmeister.com/gist/ce902d8c97b3d048e4c1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting a division by 0 error. Try starting the total from 1 :)